# $watch prevents rootScope change

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, watch, rootscope

I'm trying to get some JSON data to pass between controllers. I get some JSON with `$http`, set my callback with a `$q` defer and assign the result to my `$rootScope.productList`.
Everything is working, but when I add a `$watch` on `$rootScope.productList`, it returns me **undefined**. Do you have any solution about this?

My `$watch` inside a controller:

```
$rootScope.watch('productList', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    $scope.filters = $rootScope.productList;
    console.log($rootScope.productList);
});
```

and inside another controller, I get my data. I replaced the `$http` by a timeout to reproduce the behaviour.

```
$timeout(function() {
    $rootScope.productList = $scope.productList;
    console.log($rootScope.productList);
}, 500);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/7wWxXgq5BARYgm0tYVgf

I tried with a `$watch`, but I'd take any workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that watch() is not a recognized function - what you probably want is $watch().
In other words, you were just missing the $ next to 'watch' in your original code.

Try this:

```
$rootScope.$watch('productList', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  $scope.filters = $rootScope.productList;
  console.log($rootScope.productList);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be able to transfer data between controllers, you should be implementing a service in angular. The $rootScope wasn't created for you to set your data.